# Google Authentication OAuth2, Test Users Are Almost Meaningless?

Tags: c#, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth

So I am looking to add in an OAuth screen to a C# desktop application. I've successfully integrated the code from OAuthDesktopApp that google provides here: https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

I've created a project on Google Cloud platform, and I've generated an OAuth 2.0 Client ID.

The publishing status is "Testing", and there is a section for adding Test users. It says in a little text box:

> "While publishing status is set to "Testing", only test users are able
> to access the app. Allowed user cap prior to app verification is 100,
> and is counted over the entire lifetime of the app."

So this seems great. If a user who isn't a tester tries to use the sign-in window, the response would be some sort of "OAuth authorization error". But I've tested with a second email address that isn't listed as a tester, and it proceeds to make a call with the API to get the user info! This shouldn't happen at all if the user isn't a tester should it?

Please check this example, the code I am running is this exactly but with my own OAuth credentials (ClientID, ClientSecret). https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthDesktopApp/OAuthDesktopApp/MainWindow.xaml.cs

*Some more details about the "Why":*

I was hoping that this would be an easy way to check if a user is a "tester" for the application I am developing. I am not super concerned about security, this isn't dealing with personal information, and my application isn't for nuclear launch codes. I am just interested in a clean way of handling authentication. ie: If user logs in and the response gave an error, I would have assumed that's the expected behaviour for non-tester emails. I might do more with the Google API if this works out well!

Thank you,

Comment: I think there's an issue with this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70408186/609290

Comment: Oh, wow! Yes, it seems like that OP is having the same problem. I guess I will also wait on a fix from Google. I wasn't sure if what I noticed was the expected behavior or not, 

Thanks!